# New Flash SDD is copying as regular USB flash drive

Tags: usb, ssd, usb-flash-drive, speed, usb-storage

I bought a new Seagate OneTouch SDD of 500Gb. I tried to pass some information, but it copy at regular speed. I ran a benchmark and the result was the same of my small SanDisk USB Flash of 32Gb, both connected to the same USB 3.0 port. Does anyone have a clue about the issue? Thanks.

OneTouch SSD:

[image: benchmark SDD flash 50Gb]

SanDisk USB stick:

[image: benchmark USB flash 32Gb]

Answer (score 1):

Your benchmark is definitely at USB 2 speeds.  There can be several things causing the issue.  First, double check that your Seagate OneTouch is the USB 3 version.  Next make sure you are plugging the drive into a USB 3 port.  Many computers that support USB 3 do not have all the ports as USB 3.  They tend to mix both USB 2 and 3 versions.  It is common for a USB 3 port to be colored [blue](https://www.google.com/search?q=blue%20USB%203%20port&sxsrf=ALeKk037b39NXQFpXi7w-bmxp9Sd_TtOgg:1595300458664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR8peprd3qAhVwhHIEHZ0mC7MQ_AUoAXoECBUQAw&biw=1280&bih=592). Also not the extra pins for USB 3 in the images. However, that is not always the case.  You might have to consult your computer's manual to determine which  are the USB 3 ports, if they are not colored are marked.  Lastly, make sure you have the proper drivers for your USB controller installed.  If the wrong driver is installed, it is possible for the USB controller to work, but run at USB 2 speeds.

Comment: I already did those things. I also checked if the front USB 3 was properly connected to the board, and it is. Then I connected it to the rear USB 3 and it worked, but I want to fix the front one.

Comment: @alejorojas2k Are the front USB ports blue?  Do they have the extra pins?

Comment: Obviously I checked that

Comment: Connecting blue front connectors to USB2 connectors on the motherboard won't make them USB3 ports, however ;-) Maybe check the connectors on the motherboard.